# Search outlook 2003 using a regular expression

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, regex

Every week I have to do the same report for my bosses. Our bug tracker sends us emails, and to be sure I caught everything I often need to search Outlook for all the bug email's I've received. If I could search the email subject using a regular exrpession, my life would be much easier.

Can I search my inbox using a regular expression in Outlook 2003?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, go to Tools | Find. You can select to search by a regular expression (Ctrl+E) or Advanced Find (Ctrl+Shift+F) where you have multiple search criteria.

Comment: I don't see regex working this way in Outlook 2007. Any idea how to manage that?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if this is what your looking for but [Xobni](http://www.xobni.com/) is a great search tool for Outlook