# Search for rogue number in Outlook e-mail

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In an e-mail I have received there is a rogue 0 instead of o. If I do a search for 0 it brings up virtually every e-mail because they all have 0 in the telephone number in the signature. The specific 0 I am looking for is between 2 letters. How can I search Outlook for this e-mail?

For example it could be lo0ks has be accidentally written instead of looks and I want to find the lo0ks. I can't recall what the word.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Search outlook 2003 using a regular expression](https://superuser.com/questions/53315/)

Comment: @karel looked at that but it doesn't provide the steps on how to do it.

Comment: Make a sample text snippet with some rogue 0s in it and test your regex here: https://regex101.com/